# Android autofill shared web credentials - React Native

Tags: android, react-native, password-autofill

I'm trying to implement Android auto-fill credentials ([same as iOS shared web credentials](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/shared_web_credentials)) feature and I followed this documentation - [Smart Lock associate-apps-and-sites](https://developers.google.com/identity/smartlock-passwords/android/associate-apps-and-sites)

Here is my setup:

- development server https://dev.mydomain.com behind VPN
- but `assetlinks.json` is publicly reachable in path `https://dev.mydomain.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json`
- `assetlinks.json` content

```
[
  {
    "relation": ["delegate_permission/common.get_login_creds"],
    "target": {
      "namespace": "web",
      "site": "https://dev.mydomain.com"
    }
  },
  {
    "relation": ["delegate_permission/common.get_login_creds"],
    "target": {
      "namespace": "android_app",
      "package_name": "correct.package.name",
      "sha256_cert_fingerprints": [
        "my:app:key:verified:from:2:developers:independently:that:this:is:the:correct:key"
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

- strings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">My app name</string>
    <string name="asset_statements" translatable="false">
  [{
    \"include\": \"https://dev.mydomain.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json\"
  }]
  </string>
</resources>
```

- app published (and approved) in Closed testing channel
- app un-installed and installed again on device
- correct account credentials used for login on webpage and then on device where app is installed
- react Native version: `0.68`
- added props: [Android autocomplete](https://reactnative.dev/docs/0.68/textinput#autocomplete-android)

we triple-checked these settings and it's still not working ლ(́◉◞౪◟◉‵ლ).

questions:

- is there any other steps in configuration for React Native we are missing?
- must also be the login page publicly available?
- Smart lock is marked as deprecated in Android documentation, but when going trough recommended links it leads back again to this -> is there any other steps to make autofill work?
- any other suggestions why this is not working?

Thanks for any info/tips/help.

Answer (score 0):

Well...it seems that this feature works only on released apps in the **production** channel (internal testing and beta have not worked).

So we released the app and can confirm, it works **ONLY** in the production channel ‍♀️.

Comment: hi I am working on this. btw, did you need to implement Google OneTap signin feature? or did the autofill work after you set the assetlinks.json??

Comment: I didn't need to implement OneTap.